# How to add java project dependency to play framework 2.2.1 java project

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, playframework-2.2

I have a  couple of **java projects** (`Abc.Domain`, `Abc.Framework` etc) and I have recently created a new **playframework 2.2.1 java project** (`Abc.Rest.Api`). I am using `Eclipse` as the IDE (also tried this in `IntellijIdea`).

The hierarchy of my code base looks like as below

```
/POC (Empty project)

    /Abc.Domain (Java project/module)

    /Abc.Framework (Java project/module)

    /Abc.Rest.Api (play2 for java project/module)
```

I would like to access the classes and services of `Abc.Domain` and `Abc.Framework` in `Abc.Rest.Api`. I have tried this by adding `Abc.Domain` and `Abc.Framework` projects in `Abc.Rest.Api` Java Build Path in `Eclipse`. The project builds fine and I can access all the classes of `Abc.Domain` and `Abc.Framework` in `Abc.Rest.Api`, however when I run or Debug the `Abc.Rest.Api` the sbt of playframwork is not able to find those classes and relevant imports, resulting in runtime exceptions.

I googled about this problem and the solutions that I found are

1. Publishing `Abc.Domain` and `Abc.Framework` to `maven or ivy`
   repositories and adding them in sbt  as follows

   ```
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(    
   "org.apache.derby" % "derby" % "10.4.1.3",    
   "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final"    
   )
   ```
2. create a lib/ directory in the root of your project and then add jar
   files to that directory. They will automatically be added to the`enter code here`
   application classpath

By doing either of the above I no longer will have the capability to do realtime **debugging** and **source code navigation** to the classes and services of Abc.Domain and Abc.Framework.

I also tried this in `IntellijIdea`, ironically in IntellijIdea you can not add java modules as dependencies to playframework java module directly.

Please can anyone guide me in the right direction to **add java projects as dependencies to my playframework java project without loosing debugging and source code navigation of java projects** either by using **Eclipse** of **IntellijIdea**

Answer (score 0):

Play framework supports modules. I think you have to create modules for your project in order to access and include them in your codebase.

Other than this I think adding lib is a option but then your source code navigation and change will not work like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just create 2 jars - one with compilation output, second with sources only, I don't know how it works in Eclipse, anyway in Idea you can just `Attach sources` if missing for given jar.

You can complete it in 30 seconds (so definitely faster then configuring custom maven repo), sometimes it's required to perform `play idea` command to force IDE to reindex code of unmanaged dependencies, but finally you have the possibility to read the source code of the modules, debug as required, preview the javadoc for methods, etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am very new to `Playframework, IntellijIdea and Java`. Please can you provide step by step approach to achieve this in `IntellijIdea`.